# How does an IBM ServeRAID controller know which drive to recover during a RAID1 rebuild?

Tags: raid, raid-1, hardware-raid, ibm-server

I have an old IBM x3550 7978 server at work, which has a ServeRAID 8k-l RAID controller. I setup RAID 1 on it, and it seems to work great, but before I run any production OS on it, I want to know how the recovery procedure works.

I've spent hours looking through documentation for an answer, but so far haven't found anything. This is what I want to know:

If I unplug drive 2 and boot the OS from drive 1, the RAID will be degraded, but it will boot.

If I then unplug drive 1 and boot the OS from drive 2, the RAID will also be degraded, but will still boot.

If I connect both drives at that point and boot, which does the ServeRAID controller use as the master during the rebuild? The last one that was plugged in? The last one that had writes to it?

There's an answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/610316/434600) that explains that a generic RAID controller will probably use one of the two methods above to pick a master drive to recover. Are there other methods a RAID controller might use to pick a master? Anyone know what method my specific RAID controller might use to pick a master?

Update: I did the above experiment. In it, drive 2 was the first to get unplugged, but the last to have writes. The controller chose to clone drive 2. Was drive 2 definitely chosen because it was the last to have writes to it, or could there be a different reason it was chosen?

Comment: So you have a 2-disk RAID 1?  If you pull both disks, then there are no disks to boot from, the RAID wouldn't need to be rebuilt because the RAID  isn't degraded it simply doesn't exist.  Once the drives are replaced the system would boot.  RAID 1 doesn't offer protection from more then a single drive failure by the way.

Comment: At the most basic level: it sees which drive you unplugged and then reinserted, and that's the one that's rebuilt onto.  I'm not sure how this is a different question than the one you linked to?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 you linked to the same thing I did. That answer gives a generic answer of possible ways a raid controller might use to pick a master. I'm curious if there are other ways it might use, and what method my controller specifically would use. Also, the "whichever you unplugged and reinserted" is a pretty simplistic view of it - if a disk gets unplugged first, but has the latest writes at the time the array has enough disks to rebuild, which one gets designated as master?

Comment: I flagged it as a duplicate because it's the same question. If you'd like newer/different answers on the existing question, please earn/spend a bit of Rep and post a bounty on the existing question instead of just asking the same thing again.  OR, to avoid more duplicate closure votes, edit your question to explain how (or make sure) your question is significantly different than the existing question.

Comment: I actually just did the experiment I outlined in my question, which resulted in the drive that was unplugged first having the latest writes. The RAID controller chose the drive with the latest writes to be the master drive. Is this fairly definitive, or are there other possible reasons it may have chosen that drive as the master?

Comment: Depends on the RAID controller

Comment: I'm not real sure why you would do this. Typically the reason a RAID set needs to be rebuilt is one of the drives has failed, and is replaced. In this case the new drive is rebuilt.

Comment: Typically, the reason you have RAID 1 on server grade hardware is because you want to protect important data. Excepting that the RAID controller will "magically know" which drive to rebuild is a terrible approach. Machines are dumb things that follow very specific rules, and make assumptions. There's no magic to them. If they make the wrong assumptions, they break things. Not knowing which drive a RAID controller will recover, and hoping it's magically going to be the right one because you assume the recovery will go smoothly is just asking for trouble.